# How to calculate percentage right for multiple choice multiple answer

Tags: percentages

For school. I have a project where we had to take a survey. The questions were multiple choice and they could have multiple answers per question. For example we had one questions with 2 right answers and 7 total. We want to also penelize people who fill in wrong answers next to the right answer. For this example 100% score would be the 2 right answers and no others. Everything wrong would be none of of the right answers and then the amount of wrong answers wouldn't matter. Is there  any way to mathematicly calculate this?

Thanks already

Comment: There are many ways you could grade this. E.g. the normal way: A question gets a point only if all right answers are chosen and no wrong. Lenient way: A question can get part of a point if some right answers are chosen but no wrong (e.g. 1 right out of 2 would give a half point). Super lenient: Subtract wrong answers from right ones, i.e. 2 right answers and 1 wrong would give a half point.